# relationship for flask_sqlalchemy python3.9+

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I can't find a way to get all messages from the user via **user.messages** and the same via **channel.messages**. I keep getting an error with foreignkeys. What do I need to change to my relationships to make it work?

I would like to be able to:
**user.messages** and **channel.messages**

and as an extra (if at all possible):
**message.user.username** or **message.user.id**

my classes:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    admin = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    mc_access = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    pass_recov_code = db.Column(db.String, default=None)
    all_messages = db.relationship("Message", 
            backref=db.backref("Message"),
            primaryjoin="foreign(User.id) == remote(Message.sender_id)",
            foreign_keys="[User.id, User.username]", 
            cascade="all, delete"

            )
    
class Channel(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    uses_password = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String)
    online_users = db.Column(db.String, default=json.dumps([]))
    messages = db.relationship("Message", cascade="all, delete", foreign_keys="[Channel.id]", backref=db.backref("channel"))
    maker_id =  db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)


class Message(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    sender_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"), nullable=False)
    sender_username = db.Column(db.String, db.ForeignKey("user.username"), nullable=False)

    channel_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("channel.id"), nullable=False)

    message = db.Column(db.String, default="", nullable=False)
    send_on = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)

    edited = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply do the following:

```py
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):

    ...

    messages = db.relationship("Message", back_populates="user")


class Channel(db.Model):
    
    ...

    messages = db.relationship("Message", back_populates="channel")


class Message(db.Model):
    
    ...
    
    sender_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"), nullable=False)
    channel_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("channel.id"), nullable=False)

    user = db.relationship("User", back_populates="messages")
    channel = db.relationship("Channel", back_populates="messages")
```

This way you can use **user.messages**, **channel.messages**, **message.user.username** and **message.user.id**.

**Note:** you can also use `backref` instead of `back_populates`, but I recommend using `back_populates` as it is more explicit.